# What's the point of C's array syntax if it discards length data?

Tags: c, arrays, syntax

Here's a sample program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(int b[]){
    printf("sizeof in foo: %i\n", sizeof b);
}

int main(){
    int a[4];
    printf("sizeof in main: %i\n", sizeof a);
    foo(a);
}
```

The output is:

```
sizeof in main: 16
sizeof in foo: 8
```

Question is, what's the point of that syntax if it's just converted to a standard pointer at the function boundary?

Comment: You know, you can declare `void foo(int b[4])` if you know the size ahead of time.

Comment: @Kevin That doesn't make any difference, you could still pass an array of length other than 4 to `foo`. If you want to only allow arrays of length 4 `foo` must be `void foo( int (*b)[4] )`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. It's syntactic sugar: `void foo(int b[])` suggests that `b` is going to be used as an array (rather than a single out-parameter), even though it really is a pointer.
2. It's a left-over from [early versions of C](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/chist.html), where postfix `[]` was the syntax for a pointer declaration.

Comment: @Mehrdad: not necessarily. Syntactic sugar causes cancer of the semicolon.

Comment: @larsmans You're thinking of synthetic syntactic sugar. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synthetic_programming

Comment: @larsmans My apologies, I was referring to your comment. I was joking.

Comment: @SanJacinto: Didn't catch the joke, my bad :)

Comment: Thanks, I just thought the compilers might be a bit smarter these days and actually pass along the extra information (since, in this case, sizeof is evaluated at compile time). Can't have smart compilers without a smart standard, though :/

Comment: @Delyan: for compilers to be smart enough, they'd have to generate code that passes the size along, which would mean a hidden argument is passed; that goes against the grain of C's "you don't pay for what you don't use" philosophy.

Comment: @larsmans, surely, in cases where the size is known at compile time it can be inlined anywhere that array is used. No extra code would have to be generated, just an annotated AST in the compiler. Of course, then `int a[]` wouldn't be just syntactic sugar but a meaningful construct.

Comment: @Delyan: yes, but that would change the behavior of `sizeof` so that it depends on a function's linkage. IMHO, that would be even more confusing than the current behavior.

Answer (score 0):

> Question is, what's the point of that syntax if it's just converted to a standard pointer at the function boundary?

In this case, because you're passing the array as an argument C has created a pointer to a given address - however, the really interesting case is what happens when you allocate an array on the stack, and only use it there.

When you do this, the compiler then converts load statements for that array not into a pointer plus offset, but direct access to stack base + offset - since why not? It doesn't make sense to store the pointer anyway.

However, when it comes to passing that array around, the compiler passes the address of the base of the array to the function - as a pointer.

In short, `[]` helps you do pointer arithmetic more nicely. In the case of declaring arrays, it can be optimised away - which is why arrays are not pointers, although they are accessed via pointers in certain circumstances (and not in others).